# Getting 403 error while trying to create Pods using Custom Service Account

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created following objects in k8s cluster.

1. Namespace (**testpsp**)
2. Custom ServiceAccount (**testuser**)
3. Role and RoleBindings via. Manifest files

Please see below the yaml files for Role and RoleBinding resources.

`$ cat developer.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: developer
  namespace: testpsp
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - '*'`

`$ cat developer-binding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: developer-binding
  namespace: testpsp
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: developer
subjects:
 - kind: ServiceAccount
   name: testuser`

As you can see in above mentioned role manifest file, I have given **CREATE permission** on `Pod` resource to `testuser` Service account. But still I am getting the error.

**Error**

*Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "hello-pod.yaml": pods is forbidden: User "testuser" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "testpsp"*

Here is the Pod yaml file. Am i missing anything here?

`$ cat hello-pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-pod
  namespace: testpsp
spec:
  serviceAccountName: testuser
  containers:
  - name: hello-kubernetes
    image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.5
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080`

Here is the command that I'm running to create the Pod.

`$ kubectl --as=testuser -n testpsp create -f hello-pod.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while troubleshooting this issue, I noticed that instead of directly mentioning the ServiceAccount name in "as" flag in kubectl command, we need to use the following format

`system:serviceaccount:<namespace_name>:<serviceaccount_name>`

In my case, it will look like this - **system:serviceaccount:testpsp:testuser**

Afterwards, it started working fine.