# Kubernetes pull infomation from endpoints REST API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rbac

I trying to create a service account with permissions to get information about endpoints pod IPs and getting back a permissions problem.

Creating the service account and give it the right permissions:

```
$ kubectl create role endpoints-reader --verb=get --verb=list --resource=endpoints
$ kubectl create serviceaccount endpoints-reader-sa
$ kubectl create rolebinding default-endpoints-reader --role=endpoints-reader --serviceaccount=endpoints-reader-sa:endpoints-reader-sa
```

Adding this sa to the deployment YAML file:

```
...
spec:
  serviceAccountName: endpoints-reader-sa
  containers:
  - name: ...
```

I stated the pod and logged in into it (ssh). Now I want to run a REST call to pull the information:

```
$ TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token);
$ curl https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/XXX/endpoints --silent --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "endpoints is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:XXX:endpoints-reader-sa\" cannot list resource \"endpoints\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"XXX\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "endpoints"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK... Found the issue.

So, this line:

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-endpoints-reader --role=endpoints-reader --serviceaccount=endpoints-reader-sa:endpoints-reader-sa
```

should be changed to this:

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-endpoints-reader --role=endpoints-reader --serviceaccount=XXX:endpoints-reader-sa
```

Where `XXX` is the namespace name.
Similar problem you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384520/getting-403-error-while-trying-to-create-pods-using-custom-service-account).

Comment: Just for addition. When you are using `Role` its around one namespace. If you would like have permission cluster wide you can use `ClusterRole`. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)